# expression tableA.* doesn't work with mysql

Tags: sql, spring-boot

I'm trying to make this request but it's not accepted in Spring Boot

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableB
INNER JOIN tableA
    ON tableB.id = tableA.id
INNER JOIN tableC
    ON tableB.id = tableC.id
INNER JOIN Table D
    ON tableC.id = tableD.id
WHERE tableD.info = 'info'
```

The reason is due to the expression "tableA.*" who works perfectly in mysql workbench but not in Spring boot. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Not sure if it's in your original code but you have a space between "Table" and "D" on the final join that may not be helping. Do you have an error message at all?

Comment: You're right it's not a mistake in the code. For the moment, the only thins I can do, is to create a DTO and instanciate it but not really best practice solution....